# Spring boot Database intilization data.sql does not support store producer DDL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Spring boot Database intilization  data.sql does not support store producre data definition query.

Comment: How to solve your problem without code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.